# MVC - реализация маршрутизатора

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, mvc, маршрутизатор

Вообщем рабираюсь, пиши свой велосипед. Сама суть роутера мне понятна, возникла проблема с реализацией. Опишу немного что есть. Из index.php вызываю свой класс роутера, вызываю метод router(), сначала он берет из конфига инофрмацию о той папке в которой установлен скрипт, после чего парсит строку с передаваемыми ему данными, типа index.php/news/view/11. Разбивает ее по шаблону, шаблоны я сделал как регулярные выражения, вывел дефолтный в конфиг, типа:

```
$default_url = array('#([-_a-z0-9]+)/([-_a-z0-9]+)/([0-9]+)#' => '$1/$2/$3');
```

Плюс по задумке в модуле можно переопределить шаблон для большей гибкости. Проверяет есть ли вообще вызываемый модуль (его контроллер) в примере выше это news, есть ли у него метод view, если все ок то показываем новость с ид 11.

Мне вот интересно, насколько это все правильно ? Может можно придумать что то более гибкое ? Потому что это вечная проблема с чпу и хочется добиться максимальной гибкости и простоты)) Вот например мне захочется не site.ru/page/contacts а просто site.ru/contacts, ну избавлюсь через .htaccess от этого, но тогда возникнут проблемы с другими модулями которые могут потребовать чуть другую структуру чпу, и все это через тот же index.php.

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется немножко нецелесообразразно использовать для это регулярные выражения, они сильно грузят систему.

```
    $request = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    //user/get/id/1 - так выгледит строка запроса
    $splits = explode('/',trim($request,'/'));
    //Выбор контроллера
    $this->_controller = !empty($splits[0])?ucfirst($splits[0]).'Controller':'IndexController';
    //Выбор экшена
    $this->_action = !empty($splits[1])?$splits[1].'Action':'indexAction';
    //выбор параметров
    if(!empty($splits[2])){
        $keys = $values = array();
        for($i=2,$cnt = count($splits); $i<$cnt;$i++){
            if($i%2==0)
                $keys[] = $splits[$i];
            else
                $values[]= $splits[$i];
        }
        if($keys and $values)
            $this->_params = array_combine($keys,$values);
    }

}
Только тут ещё нужно сделать отслеживание если вдруг в строке нету какого нибудь экшена или контроллера.
```